# How to change ctrl-shift-j shortcut on Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

The shortcut to open the Developer tools is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>, but I'm used to <kbd>F12</kbd> from Firebug...

Is there a way to change this shortcut to <kbd>F12</kbd>?

Comment: `F12` for developer tools now seems to be a default shortcut.

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question is no longer relevant since Chrome added the <kbd>F12</kbd> shortcut.

Comment: Not true if you don't want ctrl-shift-j to work. I'm experiencing that now with a different shortcut.

Comment: This IS still relevant if you're a Mac user, since F12 still doesn't work in Chrome, and you have to use the awkward combination of Alt+Cmd+I. Why do they have to use annoying three key combinations when the Mac keyboard have a whooping 19 function keys!! (F1 to F19), even more F keys than a PC keyboard. So using three key combos is stupid, specially since most of those function keys have no use in Chrome...

Answer (score 10):

If you are on the Mac, you can always use the keyboard prefpane to change an hotkey. Just open Keyboard and go to hotkeys. There you can redefine any hotkey in any program you want.

Comment: To establish whether this answer is useful, first leave a comment asking which OS is in use.

Comment: i disagree. this answer can help mac users that have the same problem.

Comment: I found this helpful! I'm glad we didn't clarify whether the OP was a PC user because I might not have found this otherwise. Getting meta here but this answer does not add significant noise to the signal and is useful for any organic Mac traffic that stumbles here.

Comment: I found it useful as well.

Comment: This also doesn't work for Ctrl+Page Up or Cmd+Page Up. Damn it.

Answer (score 8):

There's an extension for remapping shortcuts that might be useful: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf. Haven't tried it yet though.

Comment: Very nice addon. I couldn't find an option to change the `ctrl shift j` though....

Comment: Doesn't work for Ctrl+Page Up (Actually Cmd+Page Up since I swapped those two keys) on Mac

Comment: The link is broken (404). If it was for the Shortkeys extension then that doesn't seem to allow you to remap existing shortcuts, only define new ones for a limited set of operations.

Answer (score -1):

Just do Right-click and hit <kbd>Inspect</kbd>.

Works on both Mac and Windows.

Comment: The question asks whether there is a way to change the Ctrl+Shift+J shortcut to F12.  I believe that you’re not answering exactly *that* question; you seem to be saying that right-click → Inspect is *an alternative way* to open the Developer tools.  If that’s what you're saying, please say it.